# Looking for correct query for where.not.any in Rails ActiveRecord

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Beginner Rails Question.
I have a table of Users and a table of Teams.

A User has many teams and Teams belong to User.

I want to query if a user does not have a team.
I'm using this query:

```
    User.joins(:teams).where.not(teams: {team_name: 'coconuts'})
```

This works except if the user has more than one team.
For example User Bill is on the coconuts team and the breadfruit team.
The above query returns Bill when he should be excluded because he is on the coconuts team.

I see why this is happening but I'm having trouble thinking of another query that will work for this scenario.
What is the correct way to grab this data?
I'm using Rails 4.

Comment: Did you tried to check the size of Teams of the users like `@user.teams.length.zero?` this returns true if user not belonging to any team, Did this solved the problem?

Comment: Hey @AmrAdel, Unfortunately this won't work as I need to know if the user is not on the team even if the user is on another team. Thanks though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using just Ruby, and not active record, you can do

```
User.select {|user| user.teams.pluck(:team_name).exclude?('coconuts') }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to the following, please consider `simple and clean code` vs `performance`:

```
team = Team.find_by(name: 'coconuts')

excluded_user_ids = team.user_ids
User.where.not(id: excluded_user_ids)

# If you want more a little bit efficiently and suppose you have the join model `Membership`
excluded_user_ids = team.memberships.pluck(:user_id)

# Or if you want more efficiently (just 1 query) and suppose you're using Postgresql
User
  .left_outer_joins(:teams)
  .group('users.id')
  .select("users.*, count(teams.id) AS count_foo, count(teams.id) filter (where teams.name = 'coconuts') AS count_bar")
  .having('count_foo != count_bar')
```

Comment: I'm not using Postgres so I'm not sure about that final query but the first query will work with a small tweak: `User.where.not(id: Team.where(team_name: 'coconuts').pluck(:user_id)).pluck(:email, :id)` -- `find_by` will only return the first result.

Comment: Doing `User.where.not(id: Team.where(team_name: 'coconuts').pluck(:user_id)).pluck(:email, :id)` is a bit faster than the accepted answer (based off very cursory testing) --- Thanks!

Comment: If you want to the collection instead of the first result, you can do like this: `excluded_user_ids  = Membership.joins(:team).where('teams.name = ? OR teams.name = ?', 'foo', 'bar').pluck(:user_id)`

Comment: Because DBMS itself has a lot of algorithms to do something like this, so we should always prefer SQL than Ruby. Trying to add a few thousand records to see the different, the Rails log may not help because it only "log" SQL time

Comment: You can search `conditional count` and tweak on the `select` clause